# Custom vaadin 14 theme. Not working with jar

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-themes

I wrote my own custom theme in vaadin following [packaging theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/custom-theme-packaging) guide.

It has following structure...

[image: structure]

Style.css has following structure...

[image]

and theme.json...

[image]

When I launch my own app from local with eclipse spring, application has following aspect...

[image]

Then I generate a jar with maven clean-install and then run exec jar with my app... If I run my app from jar, application has following aspect (jar)...

[image]

You can see differences. With exec jar, bold text has applied to buttons also text sizes... Both has the same theme and vaadin theme app jar and it has been called from pom.xml.

If I move my own theme to my app resource folder, and I do the same (generate exe jar, and run from eclipse and from jar) everything goes well and no difference between jar and eclipse run.

Do I forget something? Can you see something missing? Why exec jar add extra style or bold difference?

Thank you,

best regards.

Comment: Could you share exactly what values --lumo-size-m and --lumo-font-size-m have in each case, and also what the font-weight applied to the button's text is, and the exact CSS block that applied the font-weight in each case? You should be able to find these with the browser's css inspector.

Comment: Ah, one thing that might be wrong is that your theme should be in the frontend/themes folder, if it's part of the same project. The theme packaging instructions you referred to are for when your THEME is loaded from a separate jar, as a dependency. So I would first of all move the theme to frontend/themes.